# How to complete request with Future[StandardRoute]

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have code that simplified looks like this:

```
path("path")  {
  post {
    val routeFuture: Future[StandardRoute] = Future {
      //some app logic
      utilFunctionRoute()
    }

    ??? // complete the request
  }
}
```

At one point I have Future[StandardRoute] that contains my result but I don't know how can I complete this request without blocking on Future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `onComplete` to complete the request when dealing with futures `without blocking`. `onComplete` takes the future and then we can pattern match on `success` and `failure` to prepare the Http Response.

```
path("path")  {
  post {
    val routeFuture: Future[StandardRoute] = Future {
      utilFunctionRoute()
    }

    onComplete(routeFuture){
      case util.Success(f) =>
        complete(StatusCodes.OK)

      case util.Failure(ex) =>
        complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried onComplete construct but I was doing it in a wrong way. Now it works.